# Fourier coefficients of $\cos (\frac{x}{2})$: Need help, cannot find my mistake

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I calculated the real Fourier coefficients of $f(x) =\cos (\frac{x}{2})$ but my result does not equal the result in the solution.

**Can anyone please tell me what my mistake is?**

(Not relevant to the calculation below: $b_n$ vanish because $f$ is even and $a_0=0$)

Here is my calculation:

[image]

In the end, I simplify it to this expression:

$$ a_n = \begin{cases}  \frac{4}{2\pi (1 - 4n^2)} & n \text{ even } \\
                        \frac{-4}{2\pi (1-4n^2)} & n \text{ odd}\end{cases}$$

Which again simplifies to

$$ a_n = \frac{(-1)^n 4}{2\pi (1-4n^2)} $$

And the solution states:

$$ a_n = \frac{(-1)^n 4}{\pi (1-4n^2)} $$

At first I thought I was using the wrong formula for the coefficients but for period $2\pi$ the formula is

$$ a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi f(x) \cos(nx) dx$$

So I'm just really confused. I did the calculation twice and got the same result in every step.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \cos(nx) \ dx$ when $n \neq 0$?

Comment: First, I would need to know in what interval is $f(x)=cos(x/2)$ defined to be periodically extended. If I assume it to be $[-\pi ; \pi] $, kind of everything is wrong. Graph your function and see if you are integrating correctly, or understanding correctly where to extend the function.

Comment: @Luciano Thank you very much!